# how to fix the widget on Iphone when i click on textbox?

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile

i'm working on .Net project using Jquerymobile and asp.net on VS2010 
,when i test my application On Iphone and click on textbox that is near to the top of window the form go down a little bit and the header of page also go down with the form as i make the header not fixed, and this is happens only on Iphone so how can i prevent this action when i click on textbox ?

Comment: to be clear i have a widget contains about 8 textboxs vertically if i clicked on last text box the widget slide up and then the keypad open and this is ok for me , but if i clicked on a textbox near to the top window the widget slide down little bit i want to prevent this slide down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `this.element.addClass("ui-fixed-hidden");`
this will disable  the header to be fixed